# DVBSubtitles/Teletext Descriptors of a stream (ts-file)

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe, mediainfo, dvb, teletext

Can someone help me how to generate subtitles/teletext descriptor for according to paragraphs 6.2.41/6.2.43 ([specification](https://dvb.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/a038_tm1217r37_en300468v1_17_1_-_rev-134_-_si_specification.pdf)) , for my input ts-file?

I tried to find something suitable in mediainfo/ffprobe/ffmpeg but couldn't find anything worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Check FFmpeg's source code again:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mpegtsenc.c

[image: Subtitling descriptor part]

And the following lines:

[image: Teletext descriptor]

These lines does what you asked.